# Can we use eval to dynamically build a String and push that to build an array of subarray's?

Tags: javascript

Can we use **eval** to dynamically build a String and push that to build an array of subarray's?

in the below code **m** is a parameter passed on to the processing function, have to make **m** sized subarray's from the **originalArray**, **originalArray** could be of any length and **m<originalArray.length**

I tried the below code to build a dynamic String: **correct_m_subarray_String**

```
var dynamic_m_subarray_String = '';
for(var i=0;i<m;i++) {
    dynamic_m_subarray_String += `a[i+${i}],`;
}
var correct_m_subarray_String = dynamic_m_subarray_String.substr(0,dynamic_m_subarray_String.length-1).replace('+0','');
//output of above stmt = a[i],a[i+1],a[i+2],a[i+3], m = 4 in this case
```

next in code tried to push **correct_m_subarray_String** as `tempArray.push([eval(correct_m_subarray_String)]);`

**tempArray** should have as **m** sized subarray after the above statement but that's not happening, same thing works when hard coded as

```
tempArray.push([a[i],a[i+1],a[i+2],a[i+3]]);
```

Comment: The answer to “can we use `eval` to X” is often yes and the answer to “should we use `eval` to X” is almost always no. Why not `push` into an array?

Comment: Just use a loop and push. No need to use `eval()`. Also, Javascript arrays don't have fixed size so there is no need to worry about how to "make m sized subarrays". Simply create an array, push whatever you want into it, that's it.

Comment: To answer why your code does not work: `eval()` does not "replace your code", it parses the input string as javascript code and return the value which the code express. For example, "1,2,3,4" evaluates to `4` (see [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), you can type `1,2,3,4` in a browser console to test this), so `eval("1,2,3,4")`  returns `4`, instead of replacing the code `eval("1,2,3,4")` with code `1,2,3,4`.

Comment: @RickyMo this was helpful, so there's nothing that could make this ```tempArray.push([eval(correct_m_subarray_String)]);``` to work?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `eval()`, you can use the `slice()` method:

```
tempArray.push(...a.slice(0, m))
```

Comment: yes but further down the line have to do some more changes which could be easily done if eval resolves this as asked

Comment: `eval()` is almost never necessary.

Comment: @DevX Don't bother `eval`, ask about your real goal instead. What is the "some more changes" that make you feel hard without `eval`? You don't get a best answer for your problem if you have assumed a solution as you are asking [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: eval has use cases and won't be depreciated anytime soon, let's not go in that direction. i asked a specific thing and gave a scenario, that's the sole scope of this question.

Comment: @DevX It has uses, but they're very rare. Mainly it's when the code being evaluated is input remotely, not when you're generating it yourself.

Comment: If you're a beginner and think you need it, it's more likely to be because you just don't know the regular operations that will do what you want.

Comment: here you go, have to pass **m** parameter dynamically via an api call and this **m** would be evaluated after some computation, all this is irrelevant to question so didn't mentioned.

Comment: Anyway, I don't see why it matters what you're doing further down. It doesn't matter how `tempArray` was filled.